# Is it possible to damage internal engine using a substitute crank locking pin?

Tags: timing-belt, crankshaft, block

I have a crank pin cavity that is 9.5mm.

I have a screw-driver I'm using as a pin, with shaft that is 6mm in diameter.

I want to be sure that the pin width is sufficient to lock the engine whilst I loosen the crank pulley bolt.

Is there a general rule of thumb to minimize any risk to engine internal parts e.g. crank journals?

For example what if the bolt is a bit stiff? Perhaps a torque wrench would help to guage whether I'm applying too much pressure to loosening the crank bolt.

Comment: This is a K7M engine (renault sandero, nissan np200), 1.6l, 8valve, 2012 model.

Comment: Any input, @Paulster2 or @HandyHowie?

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to get a correctly-sized pin and use that instead of your 6mm screw driver.

You asked, "is it possible" and the answer is yes, it is possible, although not likely in my opinion, for the engine to be damaged by using the wrong sized pin.

Comment: I made enquiries, and was told "that's not a part we stock... probably a dealer-only item".

Comment: I think you should have no trouble finding some 9.5mm round stock somewhere.  Chances are you might even find a suitable screwdriver with a shaft having that diameter.

Comment: Found an 8mm bolt. It's a bit more snug so having trouble going as far in as the 6mm shaft.

I think it's far in enough now, so it's just a case of how much strain to put on a wrench or breaker-bar.

Comment: Crank bolt loose!

But now crank gear is not budging.